# Unexpected result when iterating descendants in node-set using //

Tags: java, xslt-1.0, xalan

In my simple XSLT transformation using standard JDK stuff I am getting unexpected result when using // shortcut.

```java
package my.xslt.test;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.transform.Templates;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class IssuePresenter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder xslt = new StringBuilder();
        xslt.append("<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'");
        xslt.append("                xmlns:exsl='http://exslt.org/common'");
        xslt.append("                exclude-result-prefixes='exsl'");
        xslt.append("                version='1.0'>");
        xslt.append("<xsl:output indent='yes' omit-xml-declaration='yes'/>");
        xslt.append("<xsl:variable name='tree'>");
        xslt.append("  <entry level='0'>");
        xslt.append("    <entry level='1'/>");
        xslt.append("  </entry>");
        xslt.append("</xsl:variable>");
        xslt.append("<xsl:template match='/'>");
        xslt.append("  <a><xsl:copy-of select='exsl:node-set($tree)//entry'/></a>");
        xslt.append("  <b><xsl:copy-of select='exsl:node-set($tree)/descendant::entry'/></b>");
        xslt.append("</xsl:template>");
        xslt.append("</xsl:stylesheet>");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Templates templates = transformerFactory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt.toString())));
        Transformer transformer = templates.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<document/>")), new StreamResult(writer));
        System.out.println(writer);
    }
}
```

I expect `<a>` to be same as `<b>`. Is it bug or am I missing something?

```xml
<a>
    <entry level="1"/>
</a><b>
    <entry level="0">
        <entry level="1"/>
    </entry>
    <entry level="1"/>
</b>
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your result using Xalan 2.7.1: http://xsltransform.net/pP7NbAF. Possibly an old and buggy version of JDK?

Comment: This result can be reproduced on most recent JDK 11.0.10 (provided by RedHat or GraalVM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been confirmed as a JDK bug, it can be tracked here https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8265134